# Who should be an owner of the new schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am creating a new schema in SQLServer 2008.

Should I create a new user with the same name as schema owner?

Should I use 'dbo' user as schema owner?

Comment: Why are you creating the schema? It might help answer the question

Comment: @Mike. I would like to add a unique namespace for a couple of stored procedures to one of the shared databases.  I kind of want for them to stand out from the crowd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is make the name stand out, then just use dbo. No sense creating new users and roles that you don't need.

But really, you shouldn't create a schema just to do this. Why not simply prefix the names of the procedures?

Answer (score 2):

From a security perspective the schema and all database objects should be owned by a role that cannot login yet has super user privileges.  When maintenance is to be performed you login as a non-privileged user and set your role to the super user role.